# What does the keyword 'this' means in TextView textView = new TextView(this);

Tags: java, android

What does the keyword **'this'** means in
**TextView textView = new TextView(this);**

Below is quote sniplet

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);
        setContentView(textView);
    }
    ....
```

My guess is it initialize the object textView but with what?

Comment: That 'this' is just like always: a reference to the currently used instance of the class in which that method call is made. It simply passes 'itself' as parameter to that constructor.

Answer (score 5):

It's a reference to the current `DisplayMessageActivity` instance, which serves as a `Context` for the `TextView`.

Comment: Actually, it's a reference to the current DisplayMessageActivity instance.